# Is there anything wrong with keeping 2 projects in a branch?

Tags: git

I have 2 projects in a branch of a Git repo (will only be 2 projects for the forseable future). Is there a problem with having those projects (Dev) in a single 'development' branch with both projects, i.e.:

a)

```
repo ---
       |
       developmentbranch--ProjectA
                       |
                       |--ProjectB
```

Or should it be:

b)

```
repo --- 
       |
       devBranchProjectA
       |
       |
       devBranchProjectB
```

Should it be a) or b)? Does it matter? If it does, why?

Comment: My view is that branches should either be one-offs that you'll probably get rid off once you're done (like you need to POC some change without affecting the other branches) or should eventually be merged back into the branch it came from. I see no benefit to keep separate projects in separate branches.

Comment: We'e got 53 projects in one branch fit one of our more involved websites. . It's not unusual

Comment: You should read about [git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). That will give you more clarity to understand such type of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *branch* is an orthogonal concept to a *project*.

Use branches for distinct "versions" of your code, like

- the current truth (usally `master` or `main`)
- some kind of experiment (a feature branch)
- a version that will become the truth in a short time (like a `development` or `qa` branch)
- ...

Use directories or separate repositories for distinct projects. Whether you place multiple projects in one repository or not depends on how strong the dependencies between the projects are: Will there be cases where it is important to modify multiple projects at once to keep the whole application working? Then it might be best to put those projects in one single repository.