# Is it possible that folder name can be the name of the branches?

Tags: git

I want my folder name to be the name of the branches in git. Like my folder names are A, B, C so by python or git, is there a way possible that my folder names are names of the branches in git or git takes the name of the folder and pushes it respective files to the git ?

```
Structure of my Folder
Folder: Main
Sub Folders: v1, v2, v3
```

So my branches will be v1 and v2 and v3.

Comment: You control your branch names: you create them, you rename them if you like, and so on. But Git does not push files in the first place: Git pushes *commits*. If you don't know how to use and work with *commits* (regardless of branch names), you'll get lost while using Git. Don't focus on *branch names* as they're not what Git uses.

Comment: Could you elaborate the motivation behind this?
To me, this idea defeats the entire purpose of branches. What would the content of the v2 folder be in the branch v1?
And continuing on what torek said: If your folders actually should contain versions of something, just using a single branch and maybe version tags is probably more suitable.

Comment: You will not benefit from git branches if you just store versions as files. At this point it would be easier to have a single "main" branch with all the version folders and commits together

Comment: I wonder if the motivation here is that you've come from another version control system where you had multiple branches checked out "next to each other" on the file system. One of the reasons that's not a common workflow with git is that "branches are cheap": many workflows will have you creating and deleting multiple branches *every day*, so having a separate folder each time would quickly become a mess. Setups with multiple branches checked out at once are possible, though; if you can explain what you're trying to achieve someone might be able to give some specific tips.

Comment: @Robin The motive is to get the branches to store the versions of the system. The V1 and V2 are the versions.

Comment: @Robin Exactly. That's why I need folder names as branches so that it can take versions name which is stored in folders. And folder name is the branch name.

Comment: @AmbikaSharma you are still not expressing yourself clearly. Could add a **concrete** example of the contents you intend to have in the v1/v2 folder for BOTH the v1 and v2 branch? And did you follow toreks advice and inform yourself about the basics of git, including what commits and branches are for?

Answer (score 2):

You may name your folders and branches in any way you like, though some restrictions apply to both, because technically a branch is also just a file (containing a SHA-1).

However, folders and branches are orthogonal concepts. So while one of your branches might be called "experiment_with_new_feature" you probably would not want a folder of that name.

See also my answer to here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72021450/10171966

Comment: The motive is to get the branches to store the versions of the system. The V1 and V2 are the versions.